# Different frames, same size Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I have tried weight options and such for my frame but nothing seemed to work. I have the following tables, in separate frames as I wish to delete the second one depending on the OptionMenu choice.

[image: Table]

How would I go about doing this with the following code?

```
# Not complete code, just taken areas where I've created frames and added maybe a widget
choice_frame = Frame(win1, bg='black')
choice_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)

choice_title = Label(choice_frame, text='Value %g'% float(i+1), bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
choice_title.grid(row=0, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)            
box=Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0, textvariable=svar)
box.grid(row=1, column=column+i, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1) 

frame_table = Frame(win1, bg='black')
frame_table.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)
text_table1 = Label(frame_table, text='Bearing Number', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
text_table1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
empty1 = Label(frame_table, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
empty1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
```

If more code is required please let me know. The choice_frame is in a separate definition, if that was to make a difference as well. Although I created the frame outside the definition and created the boxes inside.

Comment: when you say you want "same size frame" do you really mean that? Same height, same width? Should the columns also be the same width as the first? Or are you asking how to make the second frame the same height as the first?

Comment: You're right, I suppose I mean for the tables to purely be the same height. Each cell can be fixed to the width of the text inside as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you want is for the second frame to be the same *height* as the first frame, use sticky values of "nsew" -- you're omitting the "n" and "s" which means it doesn't expand  to fill the container.

If you really want it the same *size* (width and height, plus columns widths) it's going to take more work.

Comment: Oh yeah! This works but the 'header' row with the names doesn't come up to the same height as that of the other table. The font should be the same so I don't understand why this doesn't become the same.

Comment: I tried using .winfo_height() to find out that of the other table but by default it's 1 and if I entered height=1 into this table it doesn't work. Argh!

Comment: If you want the rows of each table to line up, the easiest thing to do is use a single table rather than two. Otherwise, you're going to have to force the height of each row to be the same.

Comment: `winfo_height` will only return 1 if the widget isn't visible. If you are using it right on a visible widget, it will return an accurate number.

Comment: I know but this second table I wish to delete depending on an OptionMenu I have.. unless there's a way of just deleting a certain section of a single table rather than creating two?